# Why is this set of polynomials not a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Why is the set of polynomials $M=\{ f(x)=2\lambda+7\lambda x +4\lambda x^2 + x^3 | \lambda \in $R$\}$ not a vector space over $R$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Does the zero polynomial belong to $M$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a vector space *under the usual addition of polynomials as addition and the usual multiplication with real numbers as scalar mutiplication*, in other words, it is not a subspace of the usual vector space of real polynomials. Indeed, the zero polynomial is not in $M$, the sum of *any* two elements of $M$ is not in $M$, and for any $c\ne 1$, the $c$-fold multiple of any element of $M$ is not in $M$.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check that if $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in M$, then $\lambda_1+\lambda_2\notin M $